# Paddings when drawing a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uilabel

I want to know what is the default top/bottom padding which gets added when we draw a label, and can we get rid of this padding completely?

Comment: Are you using IB or creating a label programmatically? I don't understand the nature of the "padding" to which you are referring.

Answer (score 2):

UILabel vertically centers whatever text it's displaying. If you want less padding, decrease the height of your label.